# Add Custom sorting for a column in google visualization table column

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-visualization

I have successfully completed a google visualization table with data coming from the database. Now I need to add a custom sorting only for one column. Ex I have a column as Status to display the level of the instance. It has several limits such as ok, critical etc. When I use the current sorting order it is displaying rows of 'ok' on top. Instead of that I need to display 'critical' rows first. To make this done I have another column as level 1 for 'critical', 2 for 'ok' etc. What I need to do is when user tries to sort 'Status' column, that column should sort according to 'level'.

```
     google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort',
              function(event) {

          if(event.column == 4){
               console.log("sorting column is "+event.column);


                data.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
               chart.draw(view);
          }


              });
```

how to add sorting order (sort with level) for Status column?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are a couple options for custom sorting a Table chart...

**first**, you can use object notation to combine the values from both columns...
set the value (`v:`) as Level and the formatted value (`f:`) as Status
`{v: 1, f: 'Critical'}`

by default, the Table chart will use the value to sort
you could also use a `DataView` to add the column from a calculation

only problem here, the column type must be `'number'`, because that's what the value is...
the chart will right align the cells for that column

if you already have custom formatting, not a big deal, you can use `css` to correct, as in the example

**next**, to custom sort using the `sort` event...

set the config option --> `sort: 'event'`

this tells the chart custom sorting is being used and to display the `data` "as ordered"

you also must provide the following two config options

```
  sortAscending: true,
  sortColumn: 0
```

this tells the chart where to put the sorting arrow on the column headings (up / down arrows)

so if you override the sort for column 1 with 0,
still need to set config option --> `sortColumn: 1`

see following working snippet,

the sort for column 1 (Status) is overridden with column 0 (Level)
column 2 (Sort) uses the object notation as mentioned above

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Level', 'Status',   'Sort'],
      [1,       'Critical', {v: 1, f: 'Critical'}],
      [2,       'OK',       {v: 2, f: 'OK'}],
      [3,       'Warning',  {v: 3, f: 'Warning'}],
      [4,       'Message',  {v: 4, f: 'Message'}]
    ]);

    var options = {
      allowHtml: true,
      cssClassNames: {
        tableCell: 'googleTableCell'
      },
      sort: 'event',
      sortAscending: true,
      sortColumn: 0
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div_table'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'sort', function (sender) {
      var sortColumn;

      // custom sort data
      switch (sender.column) {
        case 1:
          sortColumn = 0;
          break;

        default:
          sortColumn = sender.column;
      }
      data.sort([{column: sortColumn, desc: !sender.ascending}]);

      // display normal column sort arrow
      options.sortAscending = sender.ascending;
      options.sortColumn = sender.column;

      chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```css
.googleTableCell {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div_table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I already fixed this problem. Thanks again for your support.